# Convert arithmetic rgb value to 8bit RGB value

Tags: color, conversion

How to exactly convert an arithmetic `rgb` value (e.g `0.55,0.25,0.1`) to the corresponding 8bit `RGB` value (e.g. `123,90,40`)?

My more specific questions are:

1.) What is the exact conversion formula and macro?

2.) Is there some built in command or macro for converting it?

Comment: Did you have a look at "6.3  Color conversion and complements"  of the `xcolor` manual?

Comment: `rgb` values go from 0 to 0, `RGB` values go from 0 to 255, so multiply every part of the `rgb` with 255 to get the corresponding `RGB` color.  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mycolorrgb}{rgb}{0.55,0.25,0.1}
\definecolor{mycolorRGB}{RGB}{140.25,63.75,25.5}

\begin{document}

\color{mycolorrgb}\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\color{mycolorRGB}\rule{5cm}{5cm} 

\end{document}`

Comment: @leandriis Is it allowed to write RGB colors with a comma (e.g. 140.25)? Will the comma part be considered?

Comment: Can someone come up with macro which calculates RGB = floor(1/2 + 256 * rgb)? I'm not that good in calculating things in LaTeX.

Comment: Regarding your previoustwo questions also revolving around color values and conversion, could you please explain the purpose of this? What do you need the values for?

Comment: @leandriis I would like to use named colors from http://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/latexcolors/latexcolors.pdf in my document, but my document requires RGB values.

Comment: Could you please explain why your document requires RGB colors instead of rgb?

Comment: @leandriis I would like to use a macro which uses RGB values internally. To be consistent, I would also like to use RBG values instead of rgb values, otherwise it would look confusing, mixing rgb and RGB values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xcolor has commands to convert between models. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
{\color{airforceblue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\convertcolorspec{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}{RGB}\temp
\temp

%check:
\definecolor{airforceblueRGB}{RGB}{92,138,168}    
{\color{airforceblueRGB}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

[image]