# Determining the RGB Definitions of Modified Colors in LaTeX

Tags: color, definition

After defining certain colors and modifying them as the following code indicates, I then would like to determine the equivalent RGB definitions of the modified colors.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mycbox}[1]{\tikz{\path[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle (3cm,3cm);}}

\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0, 0, 1}
\definecolor{burntorange}{rgb}{0.8, 0.33, 0.0}

\begin{document}
    \mycbox{red} 
    \mycbox{blue}
    \mycbox{burntorange}
        
\vskip 30pt

\textbf{\LARGE{RGB Definitions of These Colors? ---}}

\vskip 15pt

    \mycbox{red!80} 
    \mycbox{blue!60}
    \mycbox{burntorange!65}
    \mycbox{burntorange!55!red!80}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How may I determine the exact RGB definitions of the four colors in the second row? Thank you.

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523199/2388

Comment: @Werner It does not.

Comment: @mlchristians: How about [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/yzxqMm2i) ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0dCU.png))?

Comment: @Werner Thank you for providing this. It appears to give the answers I was looking for---but I will need to study it to see if I can understand how the answers are derived. Thank you again.